# Public static double method?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {

    private static int number1 = 100;
    private static int number2 = 1;

    public static double avgAge() {

        return (number1 + number2) / 2;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Average number: " + test.avgAge());
    }   
}
```

Why does test.avgAge() = 50.0 instead of 50.5? Is there a way to output 50.5 instead?

Answer (score 3):

The calculation is done as an integer calculation.

If you replace 2 by 2.0 you will get 50.5. I recommend adding a comment to that line to explain this to future readers.
Alternatively you can explicitly cast to a double:

```
((double) (number1 + number2)) / 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Just replace this function

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {

private static int number1 = 100;
private static int number2 = 1;

public static double avgAge() {

    return (number1 + number2) / 2.0;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Average number: " + test.avgAge()); //Average number: 50.5
}   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using `ints` through out the calculation before returning it as a `double`.  Do the following:

```
private static double number1 = 100.0;
private static double number2 = 1.0;
```

Change these to `double`.  Also, change the 2 to 2.0:

```
    return (number1 + number2) / 2.0;
```

Read more about `ints` and `doubles` here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Answer (score 0):

That's because of type promotion.

If in an operation, any of the operands is a double, then the result is promoted to double.

Since here all operands are ints, the division results in an int.

[Type Promotion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6)

Answer (score -2):

```
return ((double)(number1 + number2)) / 2;
```